# https://stackoverflow.com/jobs is broken for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The same for https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit

Omg, I spent so much time on filling my CV and now it seems to be lost =(

> Oops! Something Bad Happened

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: I can duplicate: Clicking on the "Jobs" button redirects me to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fso-proxy%2Fjobs`

Comment: We're investigating; it looks like a cog fell out somewhere between two systems - some folks are kicking some of the moving parts back into place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our Careers application sporadically failed to communicate with the Stack Exchange API v2 (used to retrieve tag information).

It is now resolved, thanks for your report!